# PHP DateTime DST

Tags: php, date, timezone

I searched the PHP manual and StackOverflow too, but haven't really found a proper answer to my question. My dates are stored in UTC. Now if I do:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-03-16 14:00:00', 'UTC');
$date->setTimezone('Europe/Budapest');
```

Will DateTime::setTimezone() set DST automatically? So if I format the string, will it output 15:00:00 in summer time and 16:00:00 in winter time? Or will I have to set DST manually?

Related question, if I want to get a DST independent UTC time (that I can store), will the following work?

```
$date = new DateTime('now', 'UTC');
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or better to use simple `gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')`?

Comment: As you're pretty sure you have the answer, why not just try it?

Comment: There are countries which don't use DST. Different PHP versions have different Olson database. There might be differences in DateTime in PHP 5.2 and 5.3. There might be bugs that were fixed in maintenance release. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

In addition, this would have taken you 10 seconds to verify yourself.

*Edit:*

The correct syntax is:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-03-16 14:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

As to your second question. The timezone passed in the DateTime constructor is the 'reference' timezone.

You should still call ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')) to format it in the UTC timezone, unless the default timezone was also set to UTC (date_default_timezone_set).

Next time, try a little harder trying stuff out before asking.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, the second argument must be a DateTimeZone object.