# Time of yesterday, with DST handling php

Tags: php, datetime, dst

I want to call a function for getting 24hours time period from current time.

```
$a = (new DateTime('now'))->getTimestamp();
$b = (new DateTime('yesterday'))->getTimestamp();
$a-$b;
```

the result should be `86400`, but I get `93572` that is more than **24 hours**. 
Found this:

```
$c = (new Datetime())->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'))->getTimestamp();
```

That gave me expected result. But how it will deal with DST? If I set a cronjob at 4am, when DST changes?

Comment: I actually get something a bit different, i get something like `127471` and that's because `new DateTime('yesterday')` returns a time that is at midnight but `now` return todays date and time. You know you can use `->modify("+24 hours")` or `->modify("-24 hours")` on a `DateTime` object?

Comment: No,  I didn't know till now. What about DST? I understand that `DateTime('yesterday') returns yesterday's midnight time.

Comment: DST is already calculated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736789/php-datetime-dst for a little more information.